# Copy a file on firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to copy an existing file on firebase storage without needing to uploading it again?

I need it for a published/working version setup of my app.

Comment: Copy in what sense ? From your storage to device or some other way ?

Comment: sorry I meant copy on the firebase storage itself.

Comment: UPDATE 2021 : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#code-samples_1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no method in the Firebase Storage API to make a copy of a file that you've already uploaded.

But Firebase Storage is built on top of Google Cloud Storage, which means that you can use the latter's API too. It looks like `gsutil cp` is what you're looking for. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

> The `gsutil cp` command allows you to copy data between your local file system and the cloud, **copy data within the cloud**, and copy data between cloud storage providers.

Keep in mind that `gsutil` has full access to your storage bucket. So it is meant to be run on devices you fully trust (such as a server or your own development machine).

Comment: I guess one can use this node library to copy files (not sure if it allows copying folders though yet): https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach I ended up with for my project.

While it covers a broader case and copies all files under folder `fromFolder` to `toFolder`, it can be easily adopted to the case from the question (to copy only files one can pass delimiter = "/" - refer to [the docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) for more details)

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');


module.exports = class StorageManager{

    constructor() {
        this.storage = new Storage();
        this.bucket = this.storage.bucket(<bucket-name-here>)
    }

    listFiles(prefix, delimiter){
        return this.bucket.getFiles({prefix, delimiter});
    }
    deleteFiles(prefix, delimiter){
        return this.bucket.deleteFiles({prefix, delimiter, force: true});
    }

    copyFilesInFolder(fromFolder, toFolder){
        return this.listFiles(fromFolder)
            .then(([files]) => {
                let promiseArray = files.map(file => {
                    let fileName = file.name
                    let destination = fileName.replace(fromFolder, toFolder)
                    console.log("fileName = ", fileName, ", destination = ", destination)
                    return file.copy(destination)
                })
                return Promise.all(promiseArray)
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to copy folders (including all it's descendants) in Google Cloud Storage. Here is the solution proposed by @vir-us, simplified and for NodeJS.

```js
import type { Bucket } from '@google-cloud/storage';

/** Copy Cloud Storage resources from one folder to another. */
export const copyStorageFiles = async (input: {
  bucket: Bucket;
  fromFolder: string;
  toFolder: string;
  logger?: Console['info'];
}) => {
  const { bucket, fromFolder, toFolder, logger = console.info } = input;

  const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({ prefix: fromFolder });
  const promiseArray = files.map((file) => {
    const destination = file.name.replace(fromFolder, toFolder);
    logger("fileName = ", file.name, ", destination = ", destination);
    return file.copy(destination);
  });
  return Promise.all(promiseArray);
};
```