# Firebase web: copy file from one location to another in the same bucket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a react app which shows some image stored in firebase storage. Now after doing some changes in some data related to it, I want to copy this image from one folder to another in the same bucket. I have tried using @firebase/storage to do this but it's giving me `TypeError: Unexpected error determining execution environment: Failed to fetch` and after some changes from here and there `TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function` when I am not even using fs explicitly.

```js
const copyImage = async (eventId, imageUrl) => {
        const srcBucketName = 'gs://some-random.appspot.com'
        console.log("srcBucketName :", srcBucketName);
        const destBucketName = 'gs://some-random.appspot.com'
        console.log("destBucketName :", destBucketName);
        const imageExtension = imageUrl.split('?')[0].split('.')[5]
        const srcFilename = `folder1/${eventId}.${imageExtension}`
        console.log("Filename:", srcFilename);
        const destFilename = `folder2/${eventId}.${imageExtension}`
        await storage
            .bucket(srcBucketName)
            .file(srcFilename)
            .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFilename))
        console.log(
            `gs://${srcBucketName}/${srcFilename} copied to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFilename}.`
        )
        return 'Successful'
    }
```

and

```js
    async copyFile (imageURL, dest = 'folder2') {
        const bucketName = 'gs://some-random.appspot.com';
        let link = imageURL.split('?')[0];
        let location = link.split(/[/]+/g);
        dest = `${ dest }/${ location[location.length - 1] }`;
        let src = location.slice(4,).join('/');
        let file = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(src).copy(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(dest));
        return 'Transfered image'
    }
```

Comment: This StackOverflow thread [1] seems related to your issue. Where a third party also shared this NodeJS Client Library [2] for this purpose. In addition you can find some code snippets to copy objects from one destination to another as well here [3]. This document [4] explains how to download and upload files at Cloud Storage using React Native Firebase App. 

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/39548294/10415225 
[2] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage
[3] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy 
[4] https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Get a reference to the source file
        const filePath = `${FILES_LOCATION_JOB_ADDITIONAL_FILE_EN}/${copyFromJobId}.pdf`;
        const sourceRef = ref(storage, filePath);

        // Get the download URL of the source file
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(sourceRef);

        // Fetch the file data using the download URL
        const response = await fetch(downloadURL);
        const fileData = await response.blob();

        // Create a reference for the destination file with the new name
        const destinationRef = ref(
          storage,
          `${FILES_LOCATION_JOB_ADDITIONAL_FILE_EN}/${updatedJobId}.pdf`
        );

        // Upload the source file data to the destination location
        await uploadBytes(destinationRef, fileData);
```